# iOS IP failover (round robin), DNS with multiple A-Records

Tags: ios, networking, dns, alamofire

I would like to know what's the best (or any) practise for handling IP failover in iOS.

I found this question, which is what I would like to do:
[Java outgoing TCP connection failover based on multiple DNS results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648803/java-outgoing-tcp-connection-failover-based-on-multiple-dns-results)

There are multiple A-Records for my domain behind the DNS. Something like described [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/using-multiple-a-records-for-my-domain-do-web-browsers-ever-try-more-than-one):

```
1.1.1.1 A example.com
1.1.1.2 A example.com
1.1.1.3 A example.com
```

Most Browser know if the first one is unreachable, they will move to the second one and so on.

How does this work on iOS? Automatically? I am using Alamofire for most requests.
I have searched the web and couldn't find any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, will work. Alamofire used the native URLSession. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61488